# What happens if file already exist on ftp server?

Tags: c#, ftp

I use FtpWebRequest to upload image on ftp server. However even if file with the same name exist in destination folder, it returns same response status as it was uploaded. I got error only if subfolder that i want to use not exist  on ftp. Is it right behavior for ftp request or i missing something? Is the only way to make sure file with same name not exist is try to read or delete it before upload?

Comment: Yes, most FTP servers will silently overwrite the existing file. Checking existence of the file is a different question and answered dozen times here already.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Will it overwrite it or just ignore it? Is there any way to know it? Or it depends on internal server options that hidden from clients?

Comment: Of course it depends on the server in the end. But I do not think that any server would silently ignore an upload for whatever reason. That would be a bug.